# installing latest bash on macos 12.x

Tags: bash, macos, cp, macos-monterey

I was trying a `cp` command that ran fine under ubuntu 20, namely

```
(base) jr@Historys-MacBook-Air test % cp --backup=numbered src dest
cp: illegal option -- -
```

which struck me as weird, so checking the man page I saw

```
HISTORY
     A cp command appeared in Version 1 AT&T UNIX.
macOS 12.0                                                       February 23, 2005
```

and I figured the shell might be to blame - I  found I was in `zsh`

```
(base) jr@Historys-MacBook-Air test % echo $0
-zsh
```

and when  I start a terminal in bash its an old version:

```
(base) jr@Historys-MacBook-Air test % /bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (arm64-apple-darwin21)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

So I tried to `brew install` the latest and then chsh to it but got 'non-standard shell':

```
...
==> Pouring bash--5.1.16.arm64_monterey.bottle.tar.gz
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/bash/5.1.16: 157 files, 11.5MB
(base) jr@Historys-MacBook-Air test % /opt/homebrew/Cellar/bash/5.1.16/bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (aarch64-apple-darwin21.1.0)
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

(base) jr@Historys-MacBook-Air test % chsh -s /opt/homebrew/Cellar/bash/5.1.16/bin/bash
Changing shell for jr.
Password for jr:
chsh: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/bash/5.1.16/bin/bash: non-standard shell
```

Can anyone point out how to a. run the 5.1.16 bash and/or b. use `cp --backup=numbered` on  mac os12 (and/or c. weigh in on whether the bash version is what is breaking my cp command?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In answer to your three questions:

1. Add `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/bash/5.1.16/bin/bash` (or better, `opt/local/bin/bash` which is the symlink to it) to `/etc/shells`
2. The `cp` version that comes with macOS differs from the GNU version. It lacks the `--backup=numbered` option. You will need to install `GNU Coreutils` from `Homebrew` to obtain the behavior you want. The GNU `cp` command will be prefaced with `g` as in `gcp` for GNU `cp`.
3. Neither the `bash` nor `zsh` versions have anythig to do with the `cp` command's options or behavior.